# How to create a missing record in a relationship, upon insert of the referring one?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pocketbase

I am an amateur dev (coming from Python, Go, TS and similar languages) learning SQL for a home app (with [PocketBase](https://pocketbase.io/) that uses SQLite).

I have a table `Users` with a few text columns and one column `Country` that instead of being plain text I wanted to make a relation to another table (`Countries`).

When adding records to `Users` with a country, say, *France* I need to

- check if there is already a country named *France* in `Countries`

  - if yes, get its `id`
  - if not, create it and retrieve its `id`
- insert the record with this newly acquired information

This is a typical approach I would have in other programming languages

**My question**: since I saw in SQL examples that many operations are bundled together, I am wondering whether there is **a standard/expected way to do this operation in one shot**?
(i.e. in the `INSERT` have something like the (invented) code `VALUES('Emmanuel', 'Macron', 'France' in Countries, ...)`.
Or should I rather make several SQL calls according to the algorithm above?

Comment: yyou can use a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tablename  if not exists
values ("id" ,"France") 

with a 
as
(
select id , case when countryName = "France" then 1 else 0 end as country from tablename 
)
select * from a
```